# NGINX + Angular - How to create and write to a custom text file

Tags: angular, nginx, environment-variables, cloud-foundry

**Question:**
Is it possible to create a custom text file using NGINX and write to it?

**Details:**
I'm working on an Angular application that reads values from PCF environment variables.
Some of the values in PCF environment are confidential.

I am able to read the values from PCF environment using NGINX. But I can't pass them to **environment.prod.ts** from NGINX. Therefore, I'm passing them to the browser in the response header using the following code

```
add_header x-headername value;
```

and reading them from response header in the component using HttpClient.

I want to avoid the part of sending the confidential data to browser, therefore I want to create a temporary text file dynamically using NGINX and store the confidential data in the text file, in order to read it in the component.ts file.

Please let me know if it is possible to create custom text files in NGINX. Or if there are other ways to read environment variables from PCF in Angular.

Thank you